# Has there been a spike in Germany's birth rate?

Tags: population

I hope this is on topic here...

about 40 weeks ago Germany won the World Cup. At the time I thought there would be a noticeable jump in the Birth Rate there. I've been searching for current information but I can only find statistics as of 2014.

April 5 the would have been 40 weeks after the world Cup win. Has there been a spike in the birth rate in Germany?

Comment: ROFL! Meanwhile in Germany couples were over-excited after world Cup, birth rate rises.

Comment: Once you obtain relevant data, you could re-ask this question in the form of "how could I determine whether these data show a spike in birth rates?" In the meantime you might want to review the approaches suggested by answers at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129684.